# React state is not updating immediately after setState is being called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-functional-component

I am building the frontend of a web based software and I want to add new note every time I press add button.

But it's simply not happening. New note is being rendered only when I change the state of another object. Right below I ma attaching the code. Please help, I am stuck here.

```
const [allnotes, setAllNotes] = useState(notes)

const addNote = () => {
  let notesAllTemp = allnotes;
  allnotes.forEach((n, index) => {
  if((n.id === clickedId)){
     notesAllTemp[index].notesDescs.push({id: 
      notesAllTemp[index].notesDescs.length+1,desc:''})
      setAllNotes(notesAllTemp)
    }
  });
}
```

If anyone can figure this out, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't make mistake by directly updating the array element by its index you should first copy the array into a new array, otherwise, it will directly update the array which will cause reacjs to not to re-render the component.

Check this out

```
const [allnotes, setAllNotes] = useState(notes)

const addNote = () => {
  let notesAllTemp = [...allnotes]; // !IMPORTANT to copy array
  allnotes.forEach((n, index) => {
  if((n.id === clickedId)){
     notesAllTemp[index].notesDescs.push({id: 
      notesAllTemp[index].notesDescs.length+1,desc:''})
    }
  });
  setAllNotes(notesAllTemp);
}
```

Comment: Should `setAllNotes` be inside of `forEach`? Shouldn't the entire thing instead of `let ...` be `setAllNotes(allnotes => function that returns a new array from allnotes)`?

Comment: Oops my bad I have updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Better if you first modify the array then update at once

const [allnotes, setAllNotes] = useState(notes)

```
const addNote = () => {
  let notesAllTemp = allnotes;
  allnotes.forEach((n, index) => {
    if((n.id === clickedId)){
      notesAllTemp[index].notesDescs.push({id: 
      notesAllTemp[index].notesDescs.length+1,desc:''})
    }
  });
  setAllNotes(notesAllTemp)
}
```